# ngModel not updating in specific case

Tags: angularjs

Ok I have been staring at this code for hours and it does not make ANY sense at all...

I am trying to iterate through a list of extension types and display them in a dropdown for use with a checkbox.  The problem is my ngModel is not correct when I inspect it in the `sk-checkbox` directive.  In one case the ngModel is correct and I can see the values switch from `true -> false`, but in the other case my ngModel goes from `undefined -> true`... Why the hell would the `ng-model` work correctly for the first implementation and not the second?

**This one works**

```
{{ normalizeIcons(user.UI.Restore.Files.dataSet) | json }}
<li ng-repeat="icon in normalizeIcons(user.UI.Restore.Files.dataSet)">
    <div sk-checkbox ng-model="user.UI.Restore.Files.filter[icon]" name="icon-{{icon}}" ></div>
    <img sk-img class="extIcon {{icon}}" />
</li>
```

**This one doesn't**

```
{{ normalizeIcons() | json }}
<li ng-repeat="icon in normalizeIcons()">
   <div sk-checkbox ng-model="user.UI.Restore.Files.filter[icon]" name="icon-{{icon}}" ></div>
   <img sk-img class="extIcon {{icon}}" />
</li>
```

Here is my `normalizeIcons()` function:

```
service.normalizeIcons = function(data){
        var icons = [];

        if(data) {
            var exts = _.pluck(data, 'extension');
            var unique = _.uniq(exts);

            var iconClasses = [];
            unique.forEach(function(ext){
                iconClasses.push(ICONS.map[ext] || 'default');
            });

            icons = _.uniq(iconClasses);
        }else{
            icons = ICONS.list;
        }

        return icons;
    }
```

So the **only** difference here is in the case that works I am doing more work to parse an Angular constant, `ICONS.map`.  The case that doesn't work just uses a simple assignment to an array.

Before I was using the first implementation that works and didn't think anything of it.  Now I want to be able to just return a fixed array for my icons, however the supposedly more simple version is the one that doesn't work!

**ICONS** constant

```
{
    map: {
        'docx': 'word',
        'doc': 'word',
        'dot': 'word',
        'dotx': 'word',
        'xls': 'excel',
        'xlsx': 'excel',
        'xlt': 'excel',
        'xltx': 'excel',
        'ppt': 'powerpoint',
        'pps': 'powerpoint',
        'pptx': 'powerpoint',
        'pot': 'powerpoint',
        'potx': 'powerpoint',
        'pdf': 'adobe-pdf',
        'ai': 'adobe-ill',
        'ait': 'adobe-ill',
        'eps': 'adobe-ill',
        'psd': 'adobe-photo',
        'psb': 'adobe-photo',
        'png': 'image',
        'jpg': 'image',
        'jpeg': 'image',
        'gif': 'image',
        'tif': 'image',
        'svg': 'image',
        'vsd': 'visio',
        'vdx': 'visio',
        'vsdx': 'visio',
        'vss': 'visio',
        'vsx': 'visio',
        'vst': 'visio',
        'vtx': 'visio'
    },
    list: ['word', 'excel', 'powerpoint', 'adobe-pdf', 'adobe-ill', 'adobe-photo', 'image', 'visio', 'default']
}
```

Comment: so what does get returned? We have no idea what `ICONS.list` is

Comment: @charlietfl updated...

Comment: I have console logged them both and they arrays are identical except for the order which should have nothing to do with this.

Comment: ok...that's not an array it's a nested object. Need to use object syntax for `ng-repeat`

Comment: um.. im not iterating on the object... im iterating on `ICONS.list` which is the array at the bottom of the ICONS object

Comment: oh..my bad....was hidden from view by scroll height